# Laravel / Mongodb - How to set the collection name in Controller?

Tags: laravel, mongodb

In my laravel project I need to use Mysql and Mongodb database. For the mongodb I am using this package: https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb

I have a Model name called `Import.php`

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\Model;

class Import extends Model
{
    protected $connection = 'mongodb';
    protected $collection = 'products_46';

    // protected $table = 'projects';
}
```

and a controller called `ImportController.php`

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use App\Models\Import;
use App\Models\Projects;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection;

class ImportController extends Controller
{   
      
    public function get_all_products() {

        // Predefined key
        $predefined_keys = [ 'image_link', 'title', 'price', 'brand', 'link' ];

        // Get all the products
        $get_products = Import::paginate(10);

        return response()->json($get_products, 200);    
    }
}
```

Now, in the model you can see I set a `$collection` name which is working fine. But how can I set the collection name in controller? Becuase I need to set the collection name **dynamically**!

**Note: In my mongodb database I have these collection:
products_1, products_2, products_3 and so on .....**

Comment: by changing "protected" to "public" ? btw, when they were talking about sharding they didn't mean exactly such approach.

Comment: @AlexBlex I dont get you?

Comment: you asked how to change protected property of a model from a controller. Would making it public solve the issue?

Comment: NO, that's what I didn't ask. I need to use `collection` name in my controller.

Comment: `protected $collection = 'products_46';` this collection name?

Comment: Yes, this is the collection name.

Comment: so if you make it public you will be able to access it from anywhere, and if you make it also static you will be able to do so without instantiating the class.

Answer (score 1):

If you have 2/3 collections, then create 2/3 models with separate names and `$collection` setting and use them accordingly. But if you have more than that, or you do not want to use multiple models at all, then you have to use `DB::collection` for dynamic collection. Laravel sets its collection/table name is `protected` for security reasons and it should not be set to public.

Here is an example of using `DB`.

```
DB::collection('books')->get();
```

Or

```
$hungerGames = DB::collection('books')->where('name', 'Hunger Games')->first();
```

So for your purpose of the code change the `DB::collection('books')` to `DB::collection('product_1')`  or `DB::collection('product_2')` etc.

It is just as usual plain query builder as laravel. Nothing else.

Do not set the `$collection` to public.

Comment: using `DB::collection('products_1)->get()` is showing nothing. I got error: `"Method Illuminate\Database\MySqlConnection::collection does not exist.",…}`

Comment: Do not forget to add this at top of the controller after namespace `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;` and `use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Collection;` and 
`use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Query\Builder;`

Comment: I did it but don't work